# How to serve static images in nodejs server using absolute path in Angular 10 img tag?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, image, server

I have been searching here and not finding a solution, so I am asking. How can I serve my static images located in the nodejs server:

```
public/img
```

Nodejs (before app.listen()):

```
app.use("/api", routesIndex);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/img'));
```

Angular 10 template:

```
<img class="center" [src]="quizService.rootUrl+'/public/img/'+quizService.questions[quizService.questionProgress].imageName+'.jpg'">
```

The [src] resolves to the absolute correct path of:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/public/img/shark.jpg
```

But it shows 404 still. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by doing the following:

Nodejs added path:

```
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/img')));
```

Then in Angular created a separate assetUrl that omits the "/api" part of the baseUrl:

```
[src]="quizService.assetUrl+'/'+quizService.questions[quizService.questionProgress].imageName+'.jpg'"
```

and now my images are served.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add path of statically served directory. Just remove '/public/img/'

```
<img class="center" [src]="quizService.rootUrl + quizService.questions[quizService.questionProgress].imageName+'.jpg'">
```

You can access the all file of your served directory directly. like:

```
http://localhost:5000/shark.jpg
```

Comment: thanks @Ameer Hamza, i did try that but still does not work.

Comment: @user11317802 sorry for that please try this ``http://localhost:5000/shark.jpg`` you also dont need to add route

Comment: I am doing: [src]="quizService.rootUrl + '/' + quizService.questions[quizService.questionProgress].imageName+'.jpg'" with this in nodejs server: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '\\public\\img')); and it is not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps,

```
your image is at path Public/img/shark.jpg
```

in your app.js, this should be before any route is created

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/img'));
```

create a route as below

```
app.get('/Image/:id', function (req, res) {
    // logic to find image based on id passed, we will assume it results in shark.jpg
    const filepath = `${__dirname}/public/img/shark.jpg`;
    res.sendFile(filepath);
});
```

Now consume this endpoint from your angular code

```
localhost:{PORT_NUMBER}/Image/{ID_FOR_SHARK_IMAGE}
```

Comment: the id is the imageName property. adding the app.get is not working for me.